Datatable not working when rendered - Livewire3?
There is a component that I have listed. For example, when the button is clicked, the component is rendered. When rendered, Bootstrap Datatable is not rendered as before. Sorting, searching and pagination sections do not work. I found a solution like this, but this time the pagination parts do not look like the old CSS, but the rounded design turns into a square shape. How do I solve this?
Below is my livewire 3 blade code.
@script
<script>
    $wire.on('post-created', () => {

        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#basic-datatable').dataTable();
        });

    });
</script>
@endscript


Livewire rewrites the DOM and this causes conflicts with other JS libraries.
You can try adding a wire:ignore in the container of yout Datatable but it's hard to give a precise answer without seeing the Livewire class and the view

When you use this, when you use wire:ignore, it does not render but does not list.
